# Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, robotframework-ide

`pip install robotframework-ride`
doesn't work and gives me this, I've banged my head on all sites and still at nothing. I have latest windows, python3.9, wxpython, pygments, pypubsub and pywin32.

This is the command output.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c7obysw6\\wxpython_123f4114e462465480824b64d38d6dcd\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c7obysw6\\wxpython_123f4114e462465480824b64d38d6dcd\\setup.py'"'"';
f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');
code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-206sitcp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\wxPython'
Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What exact сommand do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The current release of RIDE does not support Python 3.9. You need to install the development version as described in the README.adoc at https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE#welcome-to-the-development-version-of-ride---next-release-will-be-version-20